# Save tokenInput values on submit

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am using a tokenInput jquery plugin that selects multiple items from a predefined list, using autocompletion as they type to find each item.

The plugin looks great and my data is being generated, but when I have tokens selected and I submit the page, the token values do not get saved. How might I save the token values on submit?

html.erb:

```
 <%= form_for @idea, :html => { :multipart => true }  do |f| %>
    <div>
       <input type="text" id="tokens" name="store_ids" />
    </div>
 <%= f.submit %>
   <% end %>
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var tokens = $('.stores').map(function(index, name) {
      var name = $(name)
      return {
        name: $(name).attr('value')
      }
   })
   $("#tokens").tokenInput(tokens);
 });
```

Rails Server log:

```
 Started GET "/ideas/bpul_dishes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-11 14:03:13 -0400
 Processing by IdeasController#show as HTML
 Parameters: {"id"=>"bpul_dishes"}
 User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 6 ORDER BY    
 `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
 Idea Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `ideas`.* FROM `ideas` WHERE `ideas`.`deleted` = 0 AND  
 `ideas`.`permalink` = 'bpul_dishes' ORDER BY `ideas`.sku ASC LIMIT 1
 Role Load (0.5ms)  SELECT DISTINCT `roles`.* FROM `roles` INNER JOIN `users_roles` ON 
 `roles`.`id` = `users_roles`.`role_id` WHERE `users_roles`.`user_id` = 6 ORDER BY name 
 asc, `roles`.name ASC
 Rendered ideas/_ideas_nav.html.erb (3.2ms)
 Store Load (0.6ms)  SELECT DISTINCT `stores`.* FROM `stores` INNER JOIN `stores_ideas` 
ON `stores`.`id` = `stores_ideas`.`store_id` WHERE `stores_ideas`.`idea_id` = 201 ORDER 
BY name asc
Taxonomy Load (0.4ms)  SELECT DISTINCT `taxonomies`.* FROM `taxonomies` INNER JOIN 
`taxonomies_ideas` ON `taxonomies`.`id` = `taxonomies_ideas`.`taxonomy_id` WHERE 
`taxonomies_ideas`.`idea_id` = 201 ORDER BY store_id
Imprintable Load (0.4ms)  SELECT DISTINCT `imprintables`.* FROM `imprintables` INNER JOIN 
`imprintables_ideas` ON `imprintables`.`id` = `imprintables_ideas`.`imprintable_id` WHERE 
`imprintables_ideas`.`idea_id` = 201
(0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `artworks` WHERE `artworks`.`idea_id` = 201
Artwork Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `artworks`.* FROM `artworks` WHERE `artworks`.`id` = 343 
ORDER BY `artworks`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `artworks` WHERE `artworks`.`idea_id` = 201   
[["idea_id", 201]]
 CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `artworks` WHERE `artworks`.`idea_id` = 201  
 [["idea_id", 201]]
 CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `artworks` WHERE `artworks`.`idea_id` = 201  
 [["idea_id", 201]]
 Color Load (0.8ms)  SELECT DISTINCT `colors`.* FROM `colors` INNER JOIN `colors_ideas` 
 ON 
 `colors`.`id` = `colors_ideas`.`color_id` WHERE `colors_ideas`.`idea_id` = 201 ORDER BY 
 name  
 asc
 Artwork Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `artworks`.* FROM `artworks` WHERE `artworks`.`idea_id` = 
 201  
 ORDER BY dimensions ASC
(0.5ms)  SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT `colors`.`id`) FROM `colors` INNER JOIN 
`colors_ideas` ON `colors`.`id` = `colors_ideas`.`color_id` WHERE 
 `colors_ideas`.`idea_id` = 
 201
 CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT `colors`.`id`) FROM `colors` INNER JOIN 
`colors_ideas` ON `colors`.`id` = `colors_ideas`.`color_id` WHERE 
 `colors_ideas`.`idea_id` =  
 201  [["idea_id", 201]]
 Rendered ideas/show.html.erb within layouts/application (23.6ms)
 Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (0.4ms)
 Rendered shared/_navigation.html.erb (0.5ms)
 Rendered shared/_main.html.erb (0.0ms)
 Completed 200 OK in 74ms (Views: 64.7ms | ActiveRecord: 7.0ms)
```

Comment: Can you post your rails server log associated with this?

Comment: is that what your looking for?

Comment: Request to create/update method of the controller would be more helpful, along with code. As you already said the get request seems to be working fine.

Comment: Another thing to look at is that the tokens you initialize tokeninput(TI) with do not have ids. TI works with a token containing a name for display purposes and an id to pass on information to backend. If your store_ids TI can have multiple tokens than the value of input would be comma saperated list of ids of selected tokens.

Comment: Yes. Please show the create/update request, not the 'get'. Scroll up in the server log, it should be there.